# How can entities be classified in both PHP and Doctrine queries without duplicating code?

Tags: php, doctrine

*(It's not that I think this is impossible, but I can't see a way of doing it without essentially expressing some code in both PHP and Doctrine to have the same result via either approach)*

I have a Doctrine Entity, with a number of properties mapping to columns in the DB.  Using those properties I can calculate a higher-level status, for example an object is Active if (it was created less than 24 hours ago or has been paid for), and has a Start Date in the past.  e.g.

```
class ExampleEntity {
    //An incomplete example!
    private $createDate;
    private $startDate;
    private $paid;

    public isActive($now) {
        return ($this->IsDateRecent($this->createDate) || $this->paid) && $this->startDate < $now;
    }

    //... etc
}
```

And I can obviously convert that logic into a Doctrine equivalent to allow me to carry out a query which returns only Active entities.  But if I want to be able to do it either way, I would need to maintain both the PHP logic and the Doctrine equivalent, which is extra work and introduces a possibility of defects.

Is there a way of somehow writing the logic so that it only needs to be written once?  Failing that, how could things be organised to minimise the extra effort, and the possibility of the two approaches diverging somehow?  For example, I could imagine somehow placing the PHP code and some equivalent code which would add additional clauses to a QueryBuilder next to each other, so that even though there are still two implementations they are at least in close proximity and can be verified as being equivalent quite simply.